# Timing of Writing at clock edge

Tags: verilog

I restart to write code of verilog, recently. I confuse that of timing of writing the reg with 
'''
always@(posedge clock)
'''.

- Is it to write value on net into reg after the posedge?
- Is it to write value on reg into reg before the posedge?

Comment: Depends on the assignment: blocking or non-blocking. Have a look at https://sutherland-hdl.com/papers/1996-CUG-presentation_nonblocking_assigns.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In real hardware the value you want to write into the register has to be stable **around** the clock edge. That is the signal has to be stable(= does not change) before the clock edge and stay that way until after the clock edge.

- The stable time before the clock edge is called the set-up time.
- The stable time after the clock edge is called the hold time.

In simulation the signal should be stable 'at' the clock edge. But the 'at' time is theoretical and is infinitesimal short.

As a rule of thumb: in normal simulation make sure the signal is stable *before* the clock edge.

Comment: I understand, the setup&hold time, this means that on a simulation source both of **net and reg** before the clock edge are written into reg after the clock edge, right?, I meet source net of after edge is written into reg at the time, so I am confused.

Comment: Set-up and hold times are normally not used in behavioral simulation. That is why I said "rule of thumb..."

Comment: Maybe discommunication, I talk about behavioral simulation so I note the **always** statement.