# Timing problem between posedge and negedge in a FSM

Tags: verilog

I have the following module:

```
module test1(
    input                               en,
    input                               clk,
    input                               burst,
    output                              out_clk
);

reg [1:0] cpt = 0;

localparam burst_beg = 0;
localparam burst_end = 1;
localparam burst_init = 2;

reg [0:1] state = burst_init;

assign out_clk = (cpt <= 1) &&  state != burst_init ? clk : 1'b0;

always @(negedge clk) begin
    if (en) begin
        case (state)
            burst_init: begin
                if (burst) begin
                    state <= burst_end;
                    cpt <= 2;
                end
            end
            burst_beg: begin
                if (!burst) begin
                    state <= burst_end;
                    cpt <= 2;
                end
                else if (cpt == 1) begin
                    cpt <= 2;
                end
                else if (cpt != 2)begin
                    cpt <= 1;
                end
            end 
            burst_end: begin
                if (burst) begin
                    state <= burst_beg; 
                    cpt <= 0;
                end
            end
            default: ;
        endcase
    end
end
endmodule
```

Its functionality is pretty simple, it lets the clk signal pass only during 2 ticks, after what it just sends a zero on the out_clk wire.

I also have a very simple module:

```
module test2 (
    input clk,
    output reg [0:3] cpt
);
    initial begin
    cpt = 0;
    end
    always @(posedge clk) begin
        cpt <= cpt + 1;
    end
endmodule
```

A simple counter that increments on every clock posedge

In sum this gives us the following top module:

```
module test (
    input clk,
    input en,
    input burst,
    output [0:3] cpt
);

test1 t1(
    .en(en),
    .clk(clk),
    .burst(burst)
);

test2 t2 (
    .clk(t1.out_clk),
    .cpt(cpt)
);

endmodule
```

Once enabled, on every burst the cpt should normally increment by 2, since only 2 clock cycles of the clk are allowed through to the out_clk. Which is what happens with the current code, here is a GtkWave screenshot to better visualise.
[image: GtkWave screen]

However here is what happends when I change the negedge in the module test1 to posedge.
[image: gtkWave screen bad]

Why does my counter increment once more? I do not seem to understand how that is possible since there have only been 2 clock cycles on the out_clk.

This question does seem to give a clue: [Timing of Writing at clock edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60451001/timing-of-writing-at-clock-edge)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should be able to create a signal count_en using the state machine which would be used as a clock enable to the counter, so that the counter can run on your main clock (same clock as the state machine).  Is there a reason this will not work?  Do you know how to create a clock enable for a synchronous counter?

Comment: Actually you are absolutely right! I have thought about it after posting the question, but still wanted to know the answer to the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if clk_out has a glitch. There might be a way to see it on your trace, but in any case it results from using 'clk' in the assign statement. The following scenario could have happened:

1. clk goes high
2. cpt and state still have old values
3. clk_out goes high (because cpt and state are still old)
4. at posedge cpt and state are evaluated to new values
5. clk_out goes down in the same simulation tick (because it is shut down by new values of cpt and state).

As a result you have a glitch not visible in a simple trace. It could be detected by `alwayse @* $display...` or by a special mode of the tracer (if exists). But nevertheless it produces a clock edge which triggers your counter.

The way to work around this issue is to make sure that the gating signals are calculated before the clock edge, or make a delay in calculation of out_clk. In your original code you calculated those signal at the negedge, way before the posedge of the clk.

Comment: Serge is correct; combinational logic will glitch; don't use combinational outputs as clocks.  There are other problems associated with this in synthesis builds like timing closure, and clock distribution (bufg use).

Comment: Why does combinational logic glitch? Is it because in real hardware it actually takes some time for the signal to be processed?

Comment: Its probably a separate SO question.  However, you can search 'verilog why does combinational logic glitch' and get several answers.  The first hit in my search results is pretty good.  [glitch](https://vlsiuniverse.blogspot.com/2017/10/glitches-in-combinational-circuits.html)  and [glitches2](https://learn.digilentinc.com/Documents/277)